# Turtle Filling Colors - I'm trying to choose the color when I call the function, so that I can easily change it in the future

Tags: python, colors, turtle-graphics

So I want to choose the color when I call the function. However, whenever I choose the color it says that the color is not defined.

```py
import turtle

def square(color):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(90)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(90)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(90)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

square(brown)
```

```
>> NameError: name 'brown' is not defined
```

Comment: IndentationError . please fix to a working [mre]. Also: look into the documentation and try `"brown"` instead of `brown` when calling the function. Code-example f.e. here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.clearstamp

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong in the code you show, but that may be just because you are not familiar with how to show code on this site. So I have corrected that for you in your question.

More important, the color should be surrounded by quotes. Python is correct: the variable `brown` is not defined but the string `"brown"` is known. Try this code:

```
import turtle

def square(color):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(90)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(90)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(90)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

square("brown")
```